# My website in Internet Explorer and Edge not correct

Tags: css, internet-explorer, joomla, microsoft-edge

I have a problem with my site in Internet Explorer and in Edge browser!

http://www.kezszobor.hu

I have error with sub menuitem text, it goes down, and i don't know what is the problem!

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably just one of several solutions, but if you change .item-wrapper and .menu-link to span instead of div tags (or change their display to inline), and change the hyperlink itself to display: inline-block, then it will show up correctly in IE.

Comment: thanks, but i don't know how can i make this, i'm not pro :S :(